# nginx redirect static file request if 404

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to redirect only static file requests from a particular directory prefix when they 404.

I've tried using try_files and it may well work still but it hasn't for me so far.

This is the scenario;

Request is for https://example.com/forums/uploads/file.jpg
File 404's
Redirect to https://cdn.example.com/file.jpg

It's the change in path that I'm finding tricky.

I don't think it's possible, but a check for a non 404 on the CDN would be great also.

Solution (Based on accepted answer);

```
location ~* /forums/uploads {
    try_files $uri @rewriteimages;
}
location @rewriteimages {
    rewrite ^/forums/uploads(.*)$ https://cdn.example.com$1 redirect;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check for the existence of a local file and redirect the client to an external URL if that file does not exist.

You can use `try_files` to test for the existence of a local file, and `rewrite` to redirect the client to the external URL.

For example:

```
location /forums/uploads/
    try_files $uri @rewrite;
}
location @rewrite {
    rewrite ^/forums/uploads(.*)$ https://cdn.example.com$1 redirect;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for more.

> I don't think it's possible, but a check for a non 404 on the CDN
>   would be great also.

Nginx takes no part in resolving the URL after it is redirected to the CDN.

Comment: Thanks. This almost worked though I needed to make a few small changes.